# hibernate how to bootstrap JPA EntityManager with customized configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

I used to use hibernate native bootstrapping approaches, where I would like to add some customized things such as triggers, customized indexes etc.

Specifically, something like this:

```
Configuration configuration = new CustomConfiguration().configure()
        .addAnnotatedClass(XXXXX.class)
        ...;

configuration.addAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(...); // add some customzied triggers and index here

// use this configure to create a hibernate native SessionFactory
```

Now our team is migrating to JPA standard APIs, so I'm wondering how should I do this with standard JPA's `EntityManagerFactory`?

The `AuxiliaryDatabaseObject` I used is a very hibernate-specific thing....so I guess the only way I do this is to get some hibernate delegate from `EntityManagerFactory` and do a hybrid bootstrapping....

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor` and register that as service through the Java service loader mechanism by adding a file `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor` with the fully qualified name of your class as content.

This service will be picked up during boot automatically. In that class, you can add your auxiliary objects.